# crPlots( ) - Only showing boxplot

Tags: r

Apologies in advance if answering this question involves stating the obvious, I am just starting out in statistics and R so have very limited knowledge.

I have used crPlots( ) in order to assess the linearity assumption of my multiple regression model. However, I am only being presented with two boxplots (see image) I expected to also see some linear plots with the individual data points as this what has been show in every example of this function I have seen.

Can anyone explain why I am only getting boxplots?

Thank you!

My code -

```
RMS$ID2 <- as.factor(RMS$gender)
RMS$age_group <- as.character(RMS$age)
lmq2 <- lm(anx ~ age_group + ID2, data = RMS)
crPlots(lmq2)
```

[image: crplot]

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Because this happens when your covariates is set as factor or character. 
This is what the documentation says:
"The model cannot contain interactions, but can contain factors. Parallel boxplots of the partial residuals are drawn for the levels of a factor." 
Check this sample code as example.

```
library(car) 

lmq1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
crPlots(lmq1)

lmq2 <- lm(mpg ~ factor(wt>2), data = mtcars)
crPlots(lmq2)
```